# Cannot import name 'get' from partially initialized module 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-import

I have problem with requests package. In past requests was working, but today for no reason it stopped working. I am just importing requests and it cause error.

Code:

> import requests

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\programovani\Python\SMSemail\test.py", line 1, in 
> import requests
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests_*init*_.py", line 43, in 
> import urllib3
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3_*init*_.py", line 11, in 
> from . import exceptions
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 3, in 
> from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 234, in create_module
> return self.load_module(spec.name)
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 209, in load_module
> mod = mod._resolve()
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 118, in _resolve
> return _import_module(self.mod)
> File "C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 87, in *import_module
> **import**(name)
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in 
> import email.parser
> File "d:\programovani\Python\SMSemail\email.py", line 1, in 
> from requests import get
> ImportError: cannot import name 'get' from partially initialized module 'requests' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\vitek\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests_*init**.py)

Screenshot:

[image: Erorr]

What I've tried:

> import requests as re

Reinstalling package.

Note: File name is different

What is causing this error? Thank you.

Comment: What is the your file name

Comment: This error shows when your file name and module name are the same.

Comment: File name is different. I tried lot of file names.

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: I 've updated question. Now you can see full error.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parts of the traceback and my interpretation:

- You're trying to run `test.py`. One of the imports in it is `import requests`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "**d:\programovani\Python\SMSemail\test.py**", line 1, in **import requests**

- This results in a (normal) longer chain of imports. Somewhere along the line in the standard library's [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#module-http.client) module there's [an import in line 71](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7e6bfd1500588e5cede4590d3a721d67f915867/Lib/http/client.py#L71): `import email.parser`

> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\**lib\http\client.py**", line 71, in **import email.parser**

- Now trouble starts, because you have a file `email.py` in the same folder as `test.py`:

> File "**d:\programovani\Python\SMSemail\email.py**", line 1, in **from requests import get** ImportError: cannot import name 'get' from partially initialized module 'requests' (most likely due to a circular import)

- This alone should be enough to derail the program. So I'm a bit puzzled about the error message you get. I pretty much got the same as you when I tried to reconstruct your situation (one file `test.py` with `import requests` and another one named `email.py` in the same folder) but it ended with:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.parser'; 'email' is not a package

- You have a `from requests import get` in `email.py`, so there is in fact a potential (unintended) circular import (program starts with importing requests and on the way to do that imports (parts of) request again -> circular):

> File "**d:\programovani\Python\SMSemail\email.py**", line 1, in **from requests import get**

Solution: Renaming `email.py` should do the job, if I'm not mistaken.