# subprocess.Popen() gives "partially uninitialized module" error

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have been writing a school assignment on the different modules in python like os, sys, and subprocess. Well, everything was going fine until I typed subprocess. Popen(), which my assignment says to use to create a new .txt document. It won't work and keeps giving me this error code that doesn't seem to have much info on it online, and my professor even said they have never seen this error msg before. I've attached my code and the error message it's giving me. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what I might be doing wrong. Thanks!

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe "/c dir C:\\ >> C:\\pythonOut.txt"')
```

...fails with the error:

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe "/c dir C:\\ >> C:\\pythonOut.txt"')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'Popen' (most likely  due to a circular import
```

I have done so much research on this error but can not seem to find any clues as to why it may be happening.

Comment: Did you maybe make your own `subprocess.py` file? Avoid doing that; keep your own files' names from conflicting with standard-library modules.

Comment: _In general_, it would be better to use `subprocess.run(r'dir C:\ >>c:\pythonOut.txt', shell=True)`, but that won't help with the problem you have now, which isn't actually specific to `subprocess` at all but is related to how it's being imported.

Comment: One thing you might do is `print(subprocess.__file__)` to see which file is _providing_ the `subprocess` module. It's _supposed_ to be coming from your Python interpreter installation, but I suspect you'll see something different; once we know _what that something is_, we'll be in a better place to solve your problem.

Comment: See [cannot import name 'get' from partially initialized module 'requests'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71927945) as an example of how this problem can be caused -- in their case it's `http.client` instead of `subprocess`, but it's the same underlying issue either way.

Comment: (and notice from that duplicate that it's not just your own `subprocess.py` that causes the problem; if you have your own code that overlaps with the name of _anything `subprocess` depends on_, that can put you in this place)